# Use case when in where Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have an error in my query, but I can't find the cause. I'd like to find the same phone number according to a condition.

I tried with if condition.

```
SELECT count(t.id) as sayi from student as t 
    inner join student s on s.id!= t.id                                  
    where case 
          when one_or_two=$one_or_two and one_or_two = 1 then 
                s.first_phone = t.first_phone 
          when one_or_two=$one_or_two and one_or_two = 2 then 
                s.sec_phone = t.sec_phone
          else 1=1
          end
    and t.id=4327
```

If $one_or_two = 1

this condition should work s.first_phone = t.first_phone

---

If $one_or_two = 2

this condition should work s.sec_phone = t.sec_phone

Comment: Providing the relevant table structure will be helpful..

Comment: You condition in case have not sense to  me .. try update your question  add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

Your condition

```
when one_or_two = $one_or_two and one_or_two = 1
```

is equivalent  at

```
 one_or_two = 1
```

so you code should be reduce  to

```
  SELECT count(t.id) as sayi 
  from student as t 
  inner join student s on s.id!= t.id                                  
  where case 
            when one_or_two = 1 
              then 
                  s.first_phone = t.first_phone 
            when one_or_two = 2 then 
                  s.sec_phone = t.sec_phone
            else 1=1
            end

      and t.id=4327
```

or

```
  SELECT count(t.id) as sayi 
  from student as t 
  inner join student s on s.id!= t.id                                  
  where case 
            when one_or_two = 1 AND   s.first_phone = t.first_phone  THEN 1 else 0 
            when one_or_two = 2 AND  s.sec_phone = t.sec_phone then 1 else 0
            else 0
            end
  and t.id=4327
```

Comment: I disagree. the two possibilities are `$one_or_two = 1` or `$one_or_two = 2`. In the former case you are correct, the condition is equivalent to `one_or_two = 1`. However in the latter case the condition is equivalent to `one_or_two = 2 and one_or_two = 1` which is false **regardless** of the value of `one_or_two`, which is not the case for the condition `one_or_two = 1`.